# What is the complexity of this while loop?

Tags: algorithm, loops, while-loop, time-complexity

Let m be the size of Array A and n be the size of Array B. What is the complexity of the following while loop?

```
while (i<n && j<m){ if (some condition) i++ else j++}
```

- Example for an array: A=[1,2,3,4] B=[1,2,3,4] the while loop executes at most 5+4 times O(m+n).
- Example for an array:  A=[1,2,3,4,7,8,9,10] B=[1,2,3,4] the while loop executes at most 4 times O(n).

I am not able to figure out how to represent the complexity of the while loop.

Comment: What's the definition or value of `Codn`? It seems like there's some context missing, we can't tell how the inputs relate to the `n`, `m` variables and how the value of `Codn` changes to affect the runtime

Comment: edited to make the problem more clear

Comment: It appears to be straightforward: **O(n+m)**.  Does that not describe the issue sufficiently?

Comment: @user10458501 It didn't make the problem/question any clearer. We still have no idea why case one executes 5+4 times, and case 2 - 4 times.

Comment: I think that if you explained more what "some condition" is, we could derive a complexity for your algorithm... perhaps that detail is why it's not clear why in each case it will execute such different times

Comment: The answer depends on the starting values of `i` and `j`. Assuming they start at 0, then the first example executes at most 3+3+1 times, and the second example executes at most 7+3+1 times. It's not clear to me why you think the second example is any different than the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One common approach is to describe the *worst-case* time complexity. In your example, the worst-case time complexity is *O*(*m* + *n*), because no matter what `some condition` is during a given loop iteration, the total number of loop iterations is at most *m* + *n*.

If it's important to emphasize that the time complexity has a lesser upper bound in some cases, then you'll need to figure out what those cases are, and find a way to express them. (For example, if a given algorithm takes an array of size *n* and has worst-case *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>) time, it might also be possible to describe it as "*O*(*mn*) time, where *m* is the number of *distinct values* in the array" — only if that's true, of course — where we've introduced an extra variable *m* to let us capture the impact on the performance of having more vs. fewer duplicate values.)